# Is there any equivalent of Buddhist Pure Land in Hinduism?

Tags: philosophy, moksha, rebirth

In East Asian Buddhism, there is a tradition called Pure Land Buddhism. Pure Land Buddhists call out the name of the Amitabha Buddha, so that when they die, he will take them to be reborn in his Pure Land, Sukhavati. Once there, they are to train under Amitabha. Since the Pure Land is believed to be free of distractions, it is considered more conducive to achieving Nirvana than our world. People reborn there will have an easy time achieving Nirvana.

Do any Hindu traditions have a similar plane of existence? A plane that is more conducive to reaching Moksha than our world?

Comment: Vaikuntha is the answer. Actually there are many similarities between pure land buddhism and some forms of Vaishnavism. Even amitabha buddha and Sri Vishnu can be equated by some. Both sects require a mantra to be chanted. I remember some Gaudiya/ISKCON sites stating the same. Infact pure land buddhism is almost similar to Vaishnavism.

Comment: Though I doubt if such things will be there in Hindu Vedic scriptures. Since pure land buddhism developed at a later time in a different manner altogether. But the similarities with Vaishnavism are uncanny.